# Reading multiple lines in bash without spawning a new subshell?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do something like

```
var=0  
grep "foo" bar | while read line; do  
   var=1  
done
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since the pipe causes the while to run in a subshell. Is there a better way to do this? I don't need to use "read" if there's another solution.

I've looked at [Bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope) which is similar, but I couldn't get anything that worked from it.

Comment: This is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you really are doing something that simplistic, you don't even need the `while read` loop.  The following would work:

```
VAR=0
grep "foo" bar && VAR=1
# ...
```

If you really do need the loop, because other things are happening in the loop, you can redirect from a `<( commands )` process substitution:

```
VAR=0
while read line ; do
    VAR=1
    # do other stuff
done <  <(grep "foo" bar)
```

Comment: ( list )? Isn't it called process substitution? http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution

Answer (score 3):

then don't use pipe ,and lose the grep

```
var=1
while read line
do  
   case "$line" in
    *foo* ) var=1
   esac   
done <"file"
echo "var after: $var"
```