# how can i find the updated counter value from a subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is my script to monitor log file. I wanted to print value 0 if there is no error found and 1 for error found. That's why i used counter variable to calculate the number of error .

Script

```
1 #!/bin/bash
      2 set -x
      3 PS4='$LINENO: '
      4
      5 source config.sh
      6 source errorList.sh
      7 counter=0
      8 timeout 10s tail -fn0 $logFile | \
      9
     10 while read line ; do
     11
     12    while read value; do
     13
     14        echo "$line" | grep "$value"
     15
     16         if [ "$line" == "$value" ]
     17         then
     18         echo "Error was found: $value"
     19         counter=$((counter+1))
     20         fi
     21    done <errorList.sh
     22 done
     23
     24 echo "counter value is:$counter"
     25 noError=0
     26 if [ $counter -eq $noError ]
     27 then
     28 echo "0"
     29 else
     30 echo "1"
     31 fi
     32
```

config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
logFile=access.log
```

errorList.sh

```
#!bin/bash
error1
error2
error3
error4
error5
error1
```

debug output:

```
./newtest.sh
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
5: source config.sh
22: logFile=access.log
6: source errorList.sh
22: error1
errorList.sh: line 2: error1: command not found
33: error2
errorList.sh: line 3: error2: command not found
44: error3
errorList.sh: line 4: error3: command not found
55: error4
errorList.sh: line 5: error4: command not found
66: error5
errorList.sh: line 6: error5: command not found
77: error1
errorList.sh: line 7: error1: command not found
7: counter=0
8: timeout 10s tail -fn0 access.log
10: read line
12: read value
14: grep '#!bin/sh'
14: echo error1
16: '[' error1 == '#!bin/sh' ']'
12: read value
14: grep error1
14: echo error1
error1
16: '[' error1 == error1 ']'
18: echo 'Error was found: error1'
Error was found: error1
19: counter=1
12: read value
14: echo error1
14: grep error2
16: '[' error1 == error2 ']'
12: read value
14: grep error3
14: echo error1
16: '[' error1 == error3 ']'
12: read value
14: echo error1
14: grep error4
16: '[' error1 == error4 ']'
12: read value
14: echo error1
14: grep error5
16: '[' error1 == error5 ']'
12: read value
14: echo error1
14: grep error1
error1
16: '[' error1 == error1 ']'
18: echo 'Error was found: error1'
Error was found: error1
19: counter=2
12: read value
10: read line
24: echo 'counter value is:0'
counter value is:0
25: noError=0
26: '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
28: echo 0
0
```

Problem: The debug output shows the counter increment worked properly in a while loop. However, the counter was somehow “reset” to 0 after the loop. The cause of this weird problem is the pipe. When we use a pipe, as in command1 | command2, command2 will be executed in a subshell. The changes that happen in a subshell won’t affect the current shell, even if it’s the same variable.

After searching some solution i have found redirect the process substitution resolve this problem but i couldn't understand how can i apply it using the tail command along?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the pipe into the outer `while` loop, and instead at the *end* of that loop (i.e. after the `done`), add a redirect from a process substitution: `... done < <(timeout 10s tail -fn0 $logFile)`. See Kaleb Pederson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376031/reading-multiple-lines-in-bash-without-spawning-a-new-subshell/2376059#2376059) and the second part of mweerden's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope/124349#124349). [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) has more options.

Comment: The answer to your question is you can't. At least with a variable. Pipes create subshells, and subshells can not modify the parent environment. Use process substitution as @GordonDavisson suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Bash 4.2 (released in 2011) or later then you can put

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

before the pipeline and the `counter` value will persist after the pipeline completes.  See [how does `shopt -s lastpipe` affect bash script behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340599/4154375).

However, a better approach may be to replace the whole pipeline (and printing of the `counter` value) with

```
counter=$(timeout 10s tail -fn0 -- "$logFile" | grep -f errorList.sh -c)
declare -p counter
```

`grep` can take a list of patterns to search for from a file, with the `-f` option.  It can also count the number of matches, with the `-c` option.  `grep` also has options for matching whole lines or whole words, and an option for searching for literal strings instead of regular expressions, which may be relevant to you.

`declare -p varname` displays the value (and attributes) of the variable named `varname` in an unambiguous way.  For debugging, it's generally better than using `echo` (or even `printf`) to show the value of the variable.

A few notes on the code in the question:

- [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several issues with it, including the fundamental problem that was causing the `counter` value to be unavailable outside the pipeline.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an invaluable tool for finding problems in Bash (and other shell) code.
- `errorList.sh` is just a list of error strings.  It's not Bash code.  It shouldn't have a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`), it shouldn't have a `.sh` extension (`.txt` would be more appropriate), and it shouldn't be `source`d in the code.
- The purpose of `echo "$line" | grep "$value"` is unclear.  Maybe it's debugging code.  In any case, `echo "$var"` doesn't work in general.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).  There's an even better option than replacing `echo` with `printf` though: `grep -- "$value" <<<"$var"`.  For information about `<<<` see the [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).  The `--` option to `grep` is to prevent a leading hyphen in `$value` causing it to be treated as a `grep` option instead of a pattern.