# Variables value gets lost in subshell

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

This bash script concatenates the names for jar files to a classpath (variable CP), in the while loop the value is correct but is lost in the subshell as descibed in this related question [Bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope)

```
#!/bin/bash
CP="AAA"
func() {
        ls -1 | while read JAR
        do
                if [ ! -z "$CP" ]; then
                        CP=${CP}':'
                fi
                CP=${CP}${JAR}
        done
        echo $CP # <-- prints AAA
}

func
```

My question is, since I can't figure out which element will be the last one, how can the value be saved.

Do I actually have to save the current value (repeatedly in the loop) to a file?

EDIT:

A colleague came up with this command sequence which works well

```
ls | xargs echo|tr ' ' :
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that using `while` in a pipeline creates a subshell, and a subshell cannot affect its parent. You can get around this in a few ways. For what you are doing now, this will suffice:

```
for JAR in *; do
    # Your stuff
done
```

Another thing to note is that you [shouldn't rely on parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) also shows you ways to avoid the subshell.

Answer (score 1):

You might find using find a bit more versatile.

For example:

```
export CP=$( find /home/depesz/q/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jar' -printf ':%p' | cut -b 2- )
```

Of course set of find options is dependant on what you need/want.

This one is closer to what you had previously:

```
export CP=$( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jar' -printf ':%f' | cut -b 2- )
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit subshells are confusing; always make them explicit by using parentheses.  To solve your problem, just move the echo inside the subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash
CP="AAA"
func() {
  ls -1 | (
    while read JAR
    do
      if [ ! -z "$CP" ]; then
        CP=${CP}':'
      fi
      CP=${CP}${JAR}
    done
    echo $CP
  )
}
func
```

Comment: This is really not particularly useful all you are doing is echoing before the function quits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, which avoid the spawning of a subshell altogether. The key is to capture the loop input into a variable (in my example called "JARS") and then redirect this variable into the loop using << EOF:

```
JARS=$(ls -1)

while read JAR
do
        if [ ! -z "$CP" ]; then
                CP=${CP}':'
        fi
        CP=${CP}${JAR}
done <<EOF
$JARS
EOF

echo $CP
```

Comment: evaluating the output of `ls` is always problematic, if the path contains a blank and such.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seem to get into actually returning the value properly, echoing out the answer is fine with a very simple routine, but say you want output of the script in action, this is useless. I don't have the best answer but I don't have much time to figure it out either, so I'm just going to suggest to output exactly what you want to a temp file and read that (surprised it hasn't been mentioned to date) :

```
#!/bin/bash
CP="AAA"
func() {
  ls -1 | (
    while read JAR
    do
      if [ ! -z "$CP" ]; then
        CP=${CP}':'
      fi
      CP=${CP}${JAR}
    done
    echo "$CP" > /tmp/cp-value-file
  )
}

func
CP=$(cat /tmp/cp-value-file)
echo $CP
```

Downside: will in some cases need to write to the disk every iteration of the loop.