# Why is this Bash script not changing the string's value?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I can't understand why **userType** is not changing.

I know for certain it's successfully reaching **determineType**, but it isn't changing the value to "bbb" when I try to print out **userType** later.

```
userType="aaa"

function determineType {
    userType="bbb"
}

function checkUser {
    cat users.csv | \
    while read userLine; do
        if [[ $userLine =~ .*$user.* ]]
            then
            determineType
            echo "1"
        fi
    done
    echo "0"
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could rephrase the question in a way that would make it less localized and more useful for other people.

Comment: Your `while` loop is a completely new subshell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope

Comment: Have a look at "global vs. local" bash variables. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/bash-variables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soulseekah said in a comment, your `while` loop is executed in a subshell. Instead, do (and, as a benefit, you get rid of the useless use of cat):

```
userType="aaa"

determineType() {
    userType="bbb"
}

checkUser() {
    while read userLine; do
        if [[ $userLine = *$user* ]]; then
            determineType
            return 1
        fi
    done < users.csv
    return 0
}
```

**Note.** I also changed a few things:

- got rid of the useless regexp since the same can be achieved with globbing,
- used more common ways of defining functions in bash,
- used `return` instead of `echo` for returning values: you'd run into the same problem again with an `echo`: you'd probably use your function checkUser in another subshell to obtain the value returned by the `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a pipe, which launch the while .. do in a subshell. 
Changing the value of a variable in a subshell won't affect the original variable

You should replace the:

```
function checkUser {
    cat users.csv | \
    while read userLine; do
        if [[ $userLine =~ .*$user.* ]]
            then
            determineType
            echo "1"
        fi
    done
    echo "0"
}
```

with

```
function checkUser {
    while read userLine; do
        if [[ $userLine =~ .*$user.* ]]
            then
            determineType
            echo "1"
        fi
    done < users.csv
    echo "0"
}
```

(This also get rid of a Useless Use Of Cat)