# Variable being reset to NULL in while loop

Tags: bash

I have been having an issue that is making me tear my hair out.  I am sure the answer is simple, but so far it has evaded me.  Logically, this is what I am trying to do:

Check the the file systems for a particular type of mount
Run a command against those mounts to get a status of up/down
If the status is up, check 1000 lines of the log file for the string "slow response"
If found, set flag to 1 and exit loop
If not, set flag to 0 and get next line until finished
If the status is down set flag to 0 and move continue
echo $flag

Unfortunately this script is only returning NULLs.  I find this strange because when I insert a echo $flag right after the assignment, it will echo the proper output.  Somewhere in this code is being reset to NULL and I am unable to find it.  Any thoughts?  As additional info, I have checked to make sure that the values of $status, $i and $line show the proper output if I insert echo statements after their assignments.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGDIR=/var/log/ceph/

df|grep osd|sed 's/.*\///'|while read i;do
   status=`ceph osd dump|grep -w "$i"|awk '{print $2}'`
   if [ $status == "up" ]; then
      tail -1000 $LOGDIR/ceph-$i.log|while read line;do
          if echo $line|grep -q "slow response";then
             let flag=1
             break
          else
             let flag=0
             continue
          fi
       done
elif [ $status == "down" ];then
       let flag=0
    fi
    echo $flag
done
```

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope

Comment: Thanks to everyone that responded.  I knew it had to be a simple fix, but I just couldn't get it right.  All of your responses were fast and helpful.  Thanks so much.  I believe that I need to go fix some other scripts now :)

Comment: What do you mean by "NULL"? That term usually refers to a C null pointer constant; I'm not aware that it has any particular meaning in the context of bash scripting. The word "NULL" doesn't appear in the bash documentation.

Comment: NULLwithout value, effect, consequence, or significance.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a [Bash FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/bash/), especially E4) *If I pipe the output of a command into `read variable`, why doesn't the output show up in $variable when the read command finishes?*

Technically, pipes and loops are created in subshells, and like any program in Unix, the environment is passed down, but changes in the environment are never passed up.

Answer (score 0):

[see this for a full explanation](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.nl/2008/08/using-bash-to-feed-command-output-to.html)

```
while read i;
  do something;
done < <(df|grep osd|sed 's/.*\///')
```

Comment: In a nutshell, avoid a subshell -- this rhymes :-)

Comment: It did, and then I realized I substituted one subshell (the `| while`) for another `< <(command )`, so sadly I had to delete my linguistic toying :(