# How to check if while loop was executed?

Tags: bash

```
cat list.txt | grep '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' | while read line; do
    fn=$(basename $line)
    do_something()
done
# TODO: check if it did something
```

In case the grep command returns nothing, it won't enter the loop and *do_something()* won't be executed.

I can't check what's in $fn outside of the while loop, see [Bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124167/bash-variable-scope).

What's the least invasive solution for checking if *do_something()* was executed here?

Comment: Why not just assign a variable inside do/done?

Comment: @klugerama Unless you are using `bash` 4.2 and the `lastpipe` option, there is no way for a variable set inside that loop to be visible afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `while` loop runs in a sub shell, it cannot propagate values back up to the parent shell. There are still ways to do what is wanted, though. Here's one:

```
if grep -q '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' list.txt       # loop will definitely run
then
  while read line
  do
    # do something with line
  done < <(grep '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' list.txt)
else                                             # no matches, loop will not run
  # do something else
fi
```

It has the side effect of running `grep` twice, which could be avoided by saving the output of `grep` and post-processing it, as suggested in another answer, but in some ways this is a bit simpler to understand...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `flag` whose value will be changed if the loop is executed. Below is a poc.

```
shopt -s lastpipe   # bash 4.2 or greater only
flag="false"
cat list.txt | grep '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' | while read line; do
    fn=$(basename $line)
    do_something()
    flag="true"
done

if [ "$flag" = "true" ]
then
    echo "loop was executed"
fi
```

You need to use the following if `while` spans a `sub-shell` (thanks to all who commented below)

```
 while read line
   do
       fn=$(basename $line)
       do_something()
       flag="true"
   done < <(grep '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' list.txt)
```

Comment: Will that really work?  The body of the while loop runs in a subshell, so I would have thought changes, even to existing variables are not propagated back up.

Comment: That doesn't work because of the different scope, see the link in my description

Comment: That depends on the particular shell. Assuming recent versions of `bash`, which seem to be most common, it will not. Older versions of, e.g. `ksh` will work, though...

Answer (score 2):

Save the output of `grep` in a variable and test it explicitly.

```
filtered=$(cat list.txt | grep ....)

if [ -z "$filtered" ] ;
  ... handle empty output ..
 else
  ... do your while loop here... 
fi
```

BTW: newlines are preserved inside the `"$filtered"`, but be sure to quote it when you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a process substitution in place of the pipeline, which would allow a flag to be usefully set:

```
flag=0
while read line; do
    flag=1
    fn=$(basename $line)
    do_something()
done < <( grep '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' list.txt )

if [[ $flag == 1 ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @chepner solution:

```
flag=0
while read line; do
    grep -q '^http://.*\.osm\..*$' <<< $line && {
      flag=1
      fn=$(basename $line)
      do_something()
    }
done < list.text

if [[ $flag == 1 ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Use then one that better fits your need.