# Why does this simple script behave differently inline and in script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple bash script for file listing:

```
$ cat process.sh
for i in *; do echo $i; done
$
```

and then I run:

```
$ ./process.sh
a
b
c
d
process.sh
$
```

and

```
$ . ./process.sh










$
```

and

```
$ for i in *; do echo $i; done










$
```

I've read [Why does Bash behave differently when called as `sh`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195377/why-does-bash-behave-different-when-called-as-sh) which explains that inline commands use `sh` instead of `bash` - is wildcard non-POSIX in this case?

- Why do I get different behaviours when executing the same code?
- How to make this example work?
- Are there any other cases to look out for?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the empty output you see; it correctly produces a file listing with both direct execution and sourcing several shells, include `bash` (3.2 and 4.3), `zsh`, and `dash`.

Comment: Can you confirm that that you have five files in the directory, named `a`-`d` and `process.sh`, and that sourcing the posted `process.sh` file results in ten blank lines? What does `ps -p $$` say?

Comment: What do you have `echo` aliassed to in your shell environment?  (Run `alias` with no arguments and look at the output.)

Comment: 1. I have files a-d and the script in the directory

2.
    $ ps -p $$
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    21858 pts/1    00:00:00 bash

3. I don't have any alias for echo command. 
4. `source process.sh` produces empty lines as well

I'm using vi editing mode? Does this have anything to do?

Comment: Ok - solved it. There was a weird `for` alias in bashrc. Thanks for the effort everyone.

Comment: Don't alias keywords.  If you think you must alias keywords, think again.  If you still think you must alias keywords, don't ask about why things don't work.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The reason was an incorrect `for` alias. Thanks for your replies.